# Linebreak in shortdesc in tooltip in adf

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a inputcombobox and I have its shortdesc attribute pointed to a String variable in a managed bean. The string contain line breaks but while rendering on browser, it seems to ignore it.

I tried workarounds for this by using pop up but it seems like showPopupBehaviour is not allowed inside inputComboBox. Also can't use javascript as it is mouse hover method is  messing up with click event on LOV of inputcombobox.

I am using jdev 11.1.1.7.2

Any ideas

Comment: can u display your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML entities in your shortDesc string.
The ones you are looking for are:

```
&#10; - Line Feed 
&#13; - Carriage Return
```

Examples:

```
  <af:outputText value="Hello StackOverFlow" shortDesc="Hallo &#13;&#10; World"/>
  <af:outputText value="Hello StackOverFlow" shortDesc="Hallo &#13; World"/>
  <af:outputText value="Hello StackOverFlow" shortDesc="Hallo &#10; World"/>
```

These will all show a tooltip with a new line.

**Edit:**
It seems that the outputText component puts the tooltip in the title attribute while the inputCombobox puts the tooltip in a `<div>`

Comment: My shortdesc is pointing to a variable in maanged bean, so using el expression where it doesn't work. It prints the character &#13;&#10;

Comment: My shortdesc looks like

shortDesc="#{backingBeanScope.Bean.prodInfoshortdesc} &#13;&#10; #{backingBeanScope.Bean.pillar}">

Comment: It still works for me when replacing the Hello and World by EL expressions, what JDev version do you use (put it in your first post)?